# Strip dynamic requires from webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, uglifyjs

I have a code similar to this:

```
export default {
  something: true,
  mockData: process.env.USE_MOCK && require('./mocks/something.js').default
};
```

`process.env.USE_MOCK` is set with `webpack.DefinePlugin` to either `true` or `false`. I use this to start my app with `USE_MOCK=true npm run dev` or `npm run dev` to either run with mock data or not.

I want Webpack to remove these dynamic require in the build process with UglifyJS' dead code elimination, but I noticed that they remain there and so `something.js` will be in the built bundle.

In my case the output is similar to:

```
module.exports = {
  something: true,
  mockData: (false) && __webpack_require__(181).default
};
```

Is there a way how I can remove that import completely from the bundle?

Btw. I think something like this works:

```
let mockData;
if (process.env.USE_MOCK) {
  mockData = require('./mocks/something.js').default;
}
export default {
  something: true,
  mockData
};
```

I'd prefer the inline require though, as I've got that pattern quite a few times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
export default {
  something: true,
  mockData: process.env.USE_MOCK ? require('./mocks/something.js').default : undefined 
};
```

Or build module export separately:

```
let module_export;
module_export.something = true;

if (process.env.USE_MOCK) {
  module_export.mockData = require('./mocks/something.js').default;
}

export module_export;
```

Comment: Indeed, the ternary operator did the trick. `process.env.USE_MOCK ? require('./mocks/something.js').default : null` also works and is a bit shorter. Thanks!